# granturl not passing the right params for quickbooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCXQmFm0bFk#t=18
My path is:

```
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot', grantUrl: 'authenticate_quickbooks_url'});
```

When I click the link it returns:
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/authenticate_quickbooks_url Why doesn't rails change the path to use the token?

When I put the path in a link_to, it returns: `quickbooks_oauth_callback_url'

ruby 1.9.3p194 - Rails 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing string as it is. Not using ruby code symbols

`"#{authenticate_quickbooks_url}"`

change your line to

```
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot', grantUrl: "#{authenticate_quickbooks_url}"});
```

Comment: No luck. It returns: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/%3C%=%20authenticate_quickbooks_url%20%%3E

Comment: I should mention that the link is located inside a .haml

Comment: Yeah for haml use Direct `"#{}`

Comment: Thanks. However, now I receive the error:
OAuth::Problem (parameter_rejected):
  app/controllers/quickbooks_controller.rb:4:in `authenticate'